# Put (ed) at the end every time (verbose-trad) and first inits problem

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex` with `verbose-trad2` option and I'm trying to change the way names are printed.

I want to have (dir.) (= (ed)) at the end of editor's name (for proceedings or collection).
It works except when you cite another time the reference.

I get

> A. Delapierre et F. Grivois, Ceci est... op. cit.

but I would like to have

> A. Delapierre et F. Grivois (dir.), Ceci est... op. cit.

like the first time it appears...

Besides, I'm not sure of my tricks to put first inits...

```
%%%%%%%%%%% latex code %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[twoside,12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, citecolor=black, filecolor=black, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=black, bookmarks=true}


\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2, hyperref,backend=biber,
language=french, maxnames=10 %%%% nom max after and al.
]{biblatex}

\FrenchFootnotes

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BIBLATEX reparametrage
%%%%% first inits then name
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}
    \or
      \ifuseprefix
        {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}
        {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%% in the bibliography Name, First Name  and Name, First Name...
\DeclareNameAlias{last-first/first-last}{last-first}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% modified to put (dir.) at the end, see also byeditor+others %%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%              
     \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}   
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%% put (dir.) at the end (byeditor) 
%
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {%%%\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}       %%%% suppress
     \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
    % \addspace                                  %%%% suppress
%     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}          %%%% 
     \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}             %%%% 
     \clearname{editor}%            %%%%%%%%% 
     \newunit     }%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{
opcit = \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{inproceedings}{art\adddotspace cit\adddot}{
        \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{article}{art\adddotspace cit\adddot}{\emph{op\adddotspace cit}\adddot}},  %%%%%%%%%%%% french subtilities
idem = {\emph{idem}},
ibidem = {\emph{ibid\adddot}},
editor = {\mkbibparens{dir.}},          %%%%%%%%%%%% (dir.) instead of ed. by default
editors = {\mkbibparens{dir.}},         %%%%%%%%%%%% (dir.) instead of eds. by default
}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% new in
\newbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{in}\nopunct\addspace}}   %%%%%%%%%%%%%% we suppress : 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% comma between reference
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace} % 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@PROCEEDINGS{delap,
  editor = {Delapierre, André and Grivois, François},
  title = {Ceci est une aventure},
  shorttitle = {Ceci est...},
  publisher = {Bordas, Paris},
  year = {2011}
}

@BOOK{desmont,
  author = {Desmont, Laurence},
  title = {Chansons contemporaines},
  shorttitle = {Chansons...},
  publisher = {Belin},
  year = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

\section*{Test}

\cite{delap}

\cite{desmont}

\cite{delap}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

From `verbose-trad2.cbx` it is apparent that, for all citation commands except `\textcite` and `\textcites`, names in subsequent/short citation labels are printed by the `cite:name` bibliography macro:

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:name}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit*{\nametitledelim}}
```

In your document preamble you can redefine this to print the same name list as the bibliography.

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:name}{%
  \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit*{\nametitledelim}}
```